# Merge/Replace associative rows from one array with the associative rows of another array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, associative-array, array-merge, array-replace

I have 2 arrays - one is hard coded and the other is data retrieved from a database.
I am trying to merge them but I'm having unexpected results.

This is the first array:

```
$base_image_array = [
    ["product_image_one" => ""],
    ["product_image_two" => ""],
    ["product_image_three" => ""],
    ["product_image_four" => ""]
];
```

This is the second array:

```
$db_product_images = [
    ["product_image_one" => "../wp-content/themes/dosco/images/products_images/355_product_image_one.jpg"],
];
```

However, when I try `array_merge($base_image_array, $db_product_images)`, I get 5 rows and the `produce_image_one` occurs more than once.

What I want to achieve is this:

```
[
    ['product_image_one' => '../wp-content/themes/dosco/images/products_images/355_product_image_one.jpg'],
    ['product_image_two' => ''],
    ['product_image_three' => ''],
    ['product_image_four' => '']
]
```

I think the multidimensional nature of the arrays is confusing me.

Comment: Do you want to overwrite the previous value if the key is duplicated across arrays?

Comment: If the nested keys are unique, then you have a fundamental data structure design problem that your array is unnecessarily deep.  This design flaw has a negative effect on data processing on this specific scenario.

Answer (score 2):

clean up your num indexed array to kv array

```
<?php

$base_image_array = array
(
 array("product_image_one" => ""),
 array("product_image_two" => ""),
 array("product_image_three" => ""),
 array("product_image_four" => "")
);

$db_product_images = array
(
 array("product_image_one" => "../wp-content/themes/dosco/images/products_images/355_product_image_one.jpg"),
);

function kv($a){
    $keys = array_map(current, array_map(array_keys, $a));
    $values = array_map(current, array_map(array_values, $a));

    return array_combine($keys, $values);
}

$base_image_array  = kv($base_image_array);
$db_product_images = kv($db_product_images);

$new_array = array_merge($base_image_array, $db_product_images);
print_r($new_array);
```

output

```
Array
(
    [product_image_one] => ../wp-content/themes/dosco/images/products_images/355_product_image_one.jpg
    [product_image_two] =>
    [product_image_three] =>
    [product_image_four] =>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the array keys in both arrays are numeric. If you want one array to overwrite the other you need to get them into a state where the array keys are strings. You could do something like this:

```php
$array_with_four = array(...); // The large array
$new_array_with_four = format_arrays($array_with_four);

$array_with_one = array(...); // The small array
$new_array_with_one = format_arrays($array_with_one);

$merged = array_merge($new_array_with_four, $new_array_with_one); // Your new results

function format_arrays($array) {
    $return_array = array(); // Blank array
    foreach ($array as $child_key => $child_data){
        $return_array[$child_key] = $child_data;
    }
    return $return_array;
}
```

There are probably better ways to loop through this with the php array functions - but this should get the job done!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was very similar to the answer by @Matthew R.

```
/* Base Array */
$base_image_array = array(
    array('product_image_one' => ''),
    array('product_image_two' => ''),
    array('product_image_three' => ''),
    array('product_image_four' => '')
);

/* Populated Array */
$db_product_images = array(
    array("product_image_one" => "../wp-content/themes/dosco/images/products_images/355_product_image_one.jpg")
);

function format_array($array) {
    $return_array = array();
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
            $return_array[$k] = $v;
        }
    }
    return $return_array;
}

$array1 = format_array($base_image_array);
$array2 = format_array($db_product_images);

$final_array = array_merge($array1, $array2);

echo '<pre>';
    print_r($final_array);
echo '</pre>';
```

The resulting output was like so:

```
Array
(
    [product_image_one] => ../wp-content/themes/dosco/images/products_images/355_product_image_one.jpg
    [product_image_two] => 
    [product_image_three] => 
    [product_image_four] => 
)
```

The final output was actually different to what I originally thought I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend directly flattening the result because assuming these subarray keys are unique, there is no benefit to the depth of the data structure.  You can unpack the two arrays with `...` (spread operator) and feed the individualized row data to `array_replace()` (or `array_merge()`) to achieve the same conceptual result:

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/v3rEV))

```
var_export(array_replace(...$base_image_array, ...$db_product_images));
```

Output:

```
array (
  'product_image_one' => '../wp-content/themes/dosco/images/products_images/355_product_image_one.jpg',
  'product_image_two' => '',
  'product_image_three' => '',
  'product_image_four' => '',
)
```

---

If you desperately need to keep the deep structure, you can recreate the initial depth by mapping every associative element as its own row.

```
var_export(
    array_map(
        fn($v) => (array) $v,
        array_replace(...$base_image_array, ...$db_product_images)
    )
);
```